# Supervisor instance on VPS (digitalocean) exits when exiting the terminal

Tags: python, service, supervisord

I'm running a supervisor instance on a VPS, but it seems to exit when I exit the terminal. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run with nohup.
you should detach the process from your current terminal or it will terminate as soon as you exit.

Comment: So I must execute `nohup /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` to start?

Comment: yes, or you can use disown after running the process

Comment: How is running with nohup different from running on screen?

Comment: Running on screen still attach the process to live tty (screen) but disown/nohup the process retach it from any parent and will not receives kill signal on parent kill

Comment: Running with nohup gives me this : `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
`

Comment: correct response. meaning if you want to see the output you should check the nohup,out. AFAIK supervisord doesn't generate any outpuy